# Is there a way to import a pandas DataFrame to Django easily?

Tags: python, sql, django, pandas

I have ~8000 CSVs with ~100 million rows total that I would like to import quickly to Django (open to suggestions if this is clearly not the way to go, but I have familiarity with Django).

I would like to use pandas to read the CSVs in as it seems to be the most efficient. I was wondering, is there a way to import them to Django objects (i.e. with a mapping) other that iterate through the rows? Or would it be best to use the `to_sql` function on the `DataFrame` object?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with it..

Comment: The dataframe is a python object, you can map functions to specific columns. If you are planning on importing to a db, you could use the `to_sql` command if you do not plan on doing any transformations. You can also join dataframes together if you want to create one huge dataframe... again, the main issue here, is that you did not give us enough information to go on